# Is there a way to tell Academia.edu "My downloading a paper is not an opt-in to be spammed with ongoing related papers"?

Tags: social-media

I started exploring for sources for a paper I am working on on Academia.edu, downloaded a few papers, and got an annoying stream of (from my perspective) unsolicited related papers in my inbox. I tried to unsubscribe.

I looked at another paper, and found a fresh stream of new papers in my inbox, and unsubscribed with the most forceful option available, and in this or a previous attempt stated I had not opted in to a stream of emails and further emails on the topic would be reported as spam. I was told I had been unsubscribed from all emails.

I looked at another article and the spam continued again.

I can easily enough set up a Gmail filter to block such emails, but as a matter of principle, is there a way to tell Academia.edu "I am downloading this paper because I just want to download this paper. I am not opting in to an open-ended stream of papers connected to the one I read."?

Comment: Avoid them like the plague. You'll find every paper they have elsewhere for free.

Comment: Sending *@academia.edu to /dev/null is probably your best option. But if you feel like kicking up a fuss, here is the direct email of the CEO. https://www.richardprice.io/contact

Comment: Report them as spam to Google. That gives them incentives not to do this.